# Divide screen by percentage

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to create a Relative layout in when it 3 views layed out vertically. The first view is text and supposed to take 10% of the screen. Second view is image and is supposed to take 50% of the screen. 3rd view is text and is supposed to take the remaining 40%.

The way I do it is that by adjusting the dimensions of the image manually and estimating that it is close to what I want by looking at it. I am sure this is not the right way. So how can I do it? Bascially how can I devide the screen percentage wise and can I do it with Relative layout

Thank you

Comment: You cannot use `RelativeLayout` if you want to use relative size. Instead, use `LinearLayout` and `android:layout_weight` to adjust the percentage.

Comment: You should use LinearLayout with android:weightSum and android:layout_weight.

Comment: "You cannot use RelativeLayout if you want to use relative size" - so maybe it should be called NonRelativeLayout - some woeful naming in Android

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You should use `LinearLayout` with `android:weightSum`.

use   `android:weightSum="100"` on the root layout and give the `android:layout_weight` according to your requirement. And `android:layout_height="0dp"` for each `View`.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="100" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="10" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="50"
        android:contentDescription="@string/image"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="40" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Awesome this is great

Comment: Is `weightSum` ever really necessary? The docs say: "If unspecified, the sum is computed by adding the `layout_weight` of all of the children."

Answer (score 3):

You can do it using `LinearLayout` and `android:layout_weight` attribute:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="5" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="4" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: +1 for correct answer but the other answer is more descriptive

Comment: Perfect answer.